# Date Range Picker in angular

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

I have implemented a date range picker from angular module.
But I need to change certain behavior of the date range picker.

In its original behavior, in the custom range option we need to select a start date and an end date every time we select that option. I need to change it such that, we must not need to select both the options every time. i.e. I can only change the start date and click apply or change the end date and click apply.

[As shown in the image if a start date is selected we need to select the end date again, clearly implying the need to select both the dates every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBx8r.png)

So it would be helpful if I get any assistance in the same angular date range picker rather than suggestions of using other date range pickers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this documentation can help https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range-popup.